# Export-CSV applies wrong formatting to DateTime columns of an SQL DataTable

Tags: .net, sql-server, datetime, powershell, csv

I am running the Powershell code included below to export the results of a simple SQL select query into a csv file. If I run the same query from SQL studio, I get a datetime like this:

> 2014-08-06 15:05:49.663

After I run it through Export-CSV and open the resultant csv file:

> 8/6/2014 3:05:49 PM

Any ideas how I can fix this in my script?

Code:

```
$ConnectionString = "Server={0};Database={1};User ID={2};Password={3};Trusted_Connection=False;Connect Timeout={4}" -f $ServerInstance,$Database,$Username,$Password,$ConnectionTimeout 
$conn=new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SQLConnection
$conn.ConnectionString=$ConnectionString
$conn.Open()
$cmd=new-object system.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand($Query,$conn)
$cmd.CommandTimeout=$QueryTimeout
$ds=New-Object system.Data.DataSet
$da=New-Object system.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter($cmd)
[void]$da.fill($ds)
$ds.Tables[0] | export-csv -Delimiter '|' -Path 'c:\test.txt' -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: What is the name of the SQL column/PS object property that contains the datetime you wish to reformat?

Comment: There are multiple columns such as these. And also there are multiple tables which I'd like to do this with, each with different column names.

Answer (score 1):

Do you know the name of the column that contains the date you are looking for? I will assume that it is called `Foo` for the purpose of this

```
$ds.Tables[0] | 
    Select-Object -ExcludeProperty Foo @{Name="Foo";Expression={([datetime]$_.Foo).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff")}},* | 
    export-csv -Delimiter '|' -Path 'c:\test.txt' -NoTypeInformation
```

Forgive me if this is useless or does not help. This assumes that the date and time detail has not already been lost from the import of data.

This will export all properties except Foo by default and in place of Foo used a calculated property to format the output string.

Comment: This doesn't work when I try it...it throws an error

Comment: @blizz it would be _really_ helpful if I knew what the error was. Could just be something simple I might actually be able to fix.

Comment: Sorry I ended up getting it working like you said but it's as if it did absolutely nothing...

$ds.Tables[0] | Select-Object -ExcludeProperty InsertDate @{Name="InsertDate";Expression={([datetime]$_.InsertDate).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff")}} | export-csv -Delimiter '|' -Path 'c:\reports\test.txt' -NoTypeInformation

Comment: @blizz What do you mean? The csv had no output? The data didnt appear correctly? My code changed nothing in the output from your example?